# How to write setter in kivy language(.kv) in python?

Tags: python, kivy

How to write this line in .kv file in python Kivy ?

```
self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
```

```
<KemAutomation>
    Label:
        text: "Select Type Of Release" + "  " + "[color=ff3333](*)[/color]"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.66, "center_y": .90}
        size_hint: (1.0, 1.0)
        font_name: "Candara"
        halign: "left"
        valign: "middle"
        markup: True
        font_size: '17dp'
```

Comment: Please add the .kv you use for the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
self.label.bind(size=self.label.setter('text_size'))
```

is equivalent to:

```
<KemAutomation>
    Label:
        text_size: self.size
        # ...
```